# Get scientific notation or more decimals from tic toc in R

Tags: r, time

I'm using TicToc in R to find the duration of a script I wrote.
When using, TicToc says the duration is 0.

I tried using digits and round to get more decimals, but R keeps giving zero as an outcome.

Can I get more decimals (if necessary in scientific notation) from tic toc? Or does anyone know how many decimals tictoc gives?

Comment: not sure bout tictoc... but the `microbenchmark`-package is pretty much the default these days for timing and benchmarking...

Comment: @Wimpel thanks! I'm using the microbenchmark-package now and it gives definitely more decimals.